# Getting permission denied error in vendor/autoload

Tags: php, xampp

In php I have been trying to upload an excel sheet and send email OTP to users, but the vendor/autoload is showing "permission denied" and not working - similar problems are occurring in other functions of php also.

> Warning:
> require(C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth\adminInterface./vendor/autoload.php):
> Failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth\adminInterface\upload.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth\adminInterface./vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth\adminInterface\upload.php:2 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth\adminInterface\upload.php on
> line 2

I wanted to setup authentication in php by uploading excel for data. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: According to the error message, it tries to access a folder name `adminInterface.`, including that dot at the end. Most likely you mis-configured some base directory config option somewhere - left out a trailing slash, where there should be one (so that concatenating with `./` still means "current folder", instead of creating a non-existent / invalid path.)

Comment: As a general rule, when PHP reports error in file A, line B, the bare minimum piece of info you need to share is the piece of code you have in file A, line B. The text in error messages has been put there by developers to assist with debugging.

Comment: The error is a simple fileystem path/permissions problem and has nothing to do with most of the things you tagged - I've edited the post for you

Comment: Yes got it, i have updated the filesystem path and it is working now thank you!!